# Python3 _sqlite3.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite3, nltk

Запускаю на сервере - не работает, решить перестановкой не могу.
Локально все в порядке.

````
    from textblob import TextBlob
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/textblob/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .blob import TextBlob, Word, Sentence, Blobber, WordList
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/textblob/blob.py", line 28, in <module>
    import nltk
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 149, in <module>
    from nltk.translate import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/translate/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from nltk.translate.meteor_score import meteor_score as meteor
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/translate/meteor_score.py", line 10, in <module>
    from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/stem/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/stem/snowball.py", line 29, in <module>
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/corpus/__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    from nltk.corpus.reader import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/__init__.py", line 105, in <module>
    from nltk.corpus.reader.panlex_lite import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/panlex_lite.py", line 15, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct```
````

Comment: А версии питона и библиотек одинаковые локально и на сервере?

Comment: да, все было установлено одно и тоже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пока не понимаю в чем могла быть причина, но установив версию python 3.6 настроив библиотеки как в прошлый раз, все прошло без проблем. Видимо проблема в sqlite3.so при первой установке 3.7 sqlite3 идет с коробки - возможно установилась с ошибками.
Много кто на других форумах советовал просто снести и установить заново python.
Видимо помогает только так.